# Change file name in module upload

Tags: magento2, frontend, file-upload, uploader

How can I change the name of the file being upload (will be changed to something random)? I can't find any docs for this and similar questions either focus on the wrong bit or are for Magento 1.

This script does work without attempting to change the name - the file is uploaded to $desintationPath (which is in the /pub directory).

```
try {
    $uploader = $this->uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'file'])
        ->setAllowCreateFolders(true)
        ->setAllowedExtensions($this->allowedExtensions)
        ->addValidateCallback('validate', $this, 'validateFile');
    if (!$uploader->save($destinationPath)) {
        throw new LocalizedException(
            __('File cannot be saved to path: $1', $destinationPath)
        );
    }
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $this->messageManager->addError(
        __("Sorry we encountered a problem. Please try again or get in touch.")
    );
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass your custom file name in `save` function as second argument.
If you check `vendor\magento\framework\File\Uploader.php::save($destinationFolder, $newFileName = null)`
You find second argument is the new file name with which you want to save.

All you have to do is

```
$uploader->save($destinationPath,YOUR_RANDOM_FILENAME);
```

And your file will be stored with the name you pass.

To Upload file with extension, use below code.

```
$uploader->save($destinationPath,YOUR_RANDOM_FILENAME.'.'.$uploader->getFileExtension());
```

Comment: @jaiminsutariya how to save it with the file extension?

Comment: @simpleguy, please check updated answer for the same.